# How to find the Fourier transfer function of a Laplacian operation?

Tags: fourier-transform, homework

My practice exam question is:

> A discrete Laplacian operation on an image $f(x,y)$ results in the following output image: 
>   $$g(x,y) = 4f(x,y) - f(x+1,y)-f(x-1,y)-f(x,y+1)-f(x,y-1)$$
>
> Find the 2 dimensional discrete Fourier transfer function of the Laplacian operation and show that the laplacian operation is a high pass filter.

I have the answer sheet, but I really don't understand it so am asking for a bit more of an explanation on the steps to solve it.

Comment: Can you be more precise in what you don't understand?

Comment: @MBaz because there's no explanation the first step in the solutions is just a bunch of e to the power of 2pi*i terms. I don't get what has been done or how. I have no clue where to start on this question

Comment: Can you add the solution to the post so someone will be able to give explanation in the step you are confused?

Comment: @NavinPrashath I think I have worked out the solution, I will post an answer with it sometime tomorrow.

Comment: As a general suggestion, when you can't solve a homework problem, your first resource should be your professor's office hours.

Comment: As a hint, try to reformulate your equation as a convolution product, such that taking the Fourier transform transforms the operation in a multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is trivial:

$$H(x,y)=4\delta(x,y)-\delta(x+1,y)-\delta(x-1,y)-\delta(x,y+1)-\delta(x,y-1)$$

Or in a coefficient representation:

$$H_{xy}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\ 
-1 & 4 & -1\\ 
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is a representation of the 2D derivative operator, which is known to have a "high filtering" shape both in $x$ and $y$ axis